# Does Redirection to public page from search result is property of search portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I used search portlet in my portal. And when i click on the search result always it redirects to result's public page. E.g: I searched for a site through site name. And the result comes. When i click on the result it redirect always redirect me to site's public page, even i am the member of the site.
I want when if user is the member of the site, it must be redirected to the site's private page.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook the search portlet. In the main_search_result_form.jsp you can change the URL to your private page.
Make changes in the below lines.

```
viewFullContentURL = _getViewFullContentURL(request, themeDisplay, PortletKeys.ASSET_PUBLISHER, document);

viewFullContentURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/asset_publisher/view_content");

if (Validator.isNotNull(returnToFullPageURL)) {
    viewFullContentURL.setParameter("returnToFullPageURL", returnToFullPageURL);
}

viewFullContentURL.setParameter("assetEntryId", String.valueOf(assetEntry.getEntryId()));
viewFullContentURL.setParameter("type", assetRendererFactory.getType());

if (Validator.isNotNull(assetRenderer.getUrlTitle())) {
    if ((assetRenderer.getGroupId() > 0) && (assetRenderer.getGroupId() != scopeGroupId)) {
        viewFullContentURL.setParameter("groupId", String.valueOf(assetRenderer.getGroupId()));
    }

    viewFullContentURL.setParameter("urlTitle", assetRenderer.getUrlTitle());
}
```